# Python Generator for streaming data

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

As far as I understand, generators are useful when you want to generate a value on the fly and don't want to have saved all values to memory prior to that.

Can Generator be applied to data that is being streamed? Like for the data that is being `read()` from a `serial_port`?

My problem is how the function that generates the data ,`serial_port.read()`, should be enclosed in a function `f_encloses_serial_read()` that returns the generator. We can't know when data will arrive, so we can't just call `f_encloses_serial_read()`  to `yield` new data. It might not have one now, but maybe later it will have new one.

Comment: The answer is yes, why not?

Comment: Depends on your semantics, do you want to keep running code until data is available, then you may need to look at an event loop, e.g. `asyncio`.

Comment: Please refer to updated question, I tried to explain where I think there is the problem.

Comment: `We can't know when data will arrive, so we can't just call` Why not? I assume that `serial_port.read()` will block until there's data. What's wrong with that?